# Test class try catch on rest callout

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, rest, try-catch

So i am making post request and catch error by checking status code and by try catch too. And how can i test try catch block? I think mock response is useless here.
So requst looks like:

```
public void PostReq() {
try {
//callout
}
catch (Exception e) {

}
```

And mock if needed

```
@IsTest
global with sharing class RestHttpCalloutMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    protected Integer code;
    protected String status;
    protected String body;
    protected Map<String, String> responseHeaders = null;

    global RestHttpCalloutMock(Integer code, String status, String body, Map<String, String> responseHeaders) {
        this.code = code;
        this.status = status;
        this.body = body;
        this.responseHeaders = responseHeaders;
    }

    global HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req) {

        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        if (responseHeaders != null) {
            for (String key : this.responseHeaders.keySet()) {
                res.setHeader(key, this.responseHeaders.get(key));
            }
        }
        if (this.body != null) {
            res.setBody(this.body);
        }
        if (this.code != null) {
            res.setStatusCode(this.code);
        }
        if (this.status != null) {
            res.setStatus(this.status);
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

Also tried something like that, but it doesnt work

```
@TestVisible class UnauthorizedEndpointResponse implements HttpCalloutMock {
public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request) {
CalloutException e = (CalloutException)CalloutException.class.newInstance();
e.setMessage('Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings.');
throw e;
}
}
```

Comment: What errors are you expecting to catch?

Comment: @Girbot for exampe it works when method is wrong(PATCH - PTCH).

Comment: @PrzemysławDługoszewski-Tamoń seems good, i will write after trying